# LLDB memory read error after enabling MMU in bare-metal ARM64 app

Tags: lldb, arm64, bare-metal

I'm using LLDB to debug a bare-metal application running on ARM64. I'm running into an issue where after enabling the MMU, I'm getting memory access errors from LLDB, but the application can still access these addresses and is still running fine.

This is my setup:

- `clang+llvm-16.0.0-arm64-apple-darwin22.0` for cross-compilation and also for debugging
- qemu 7.2.0 to emulate a Raspberry Pi 3A+
- After building the kernel ELF, I use `llvm-objcopy` to strip out the binary and give it to qemu
- `lldb` is attached to qemu with:

  - `target create <path to kernel8.elf>`
  - `gdb-remote localhost:1234`

Everything works fine but after the instruction to enable MMU, I'm getting memory read error from LLDB, such as:

```
(lldb) n
Process 1 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = instruction step over
    frame #0: 0x000000800020a004 kernel8.elf`kernel_main + 4
error: memory read failed for 0x20a000

(lldb) memory read 0x000000800020a004
error: memory read failed for 0x20a000
```

Any ideas what I'm missing with my setup here?

Comment: `read failed for 0x20a000`, looks like address is cut to 32b. Are you sure that correct 64b version of lldb from arm64 toolchain is used ? rather than some default 32b version in qemu.

Comment: yep I used `lldb` from `clang+llvm-16.0.0-arm64-apple-darwin22.0` which is for arm64, not sure why it shows the failed address is 32b

Comment: By default, lldb uses a page-based memory cache and to service that it fetches memory on page boundaries.  That's why the request was rounded down.  You can turn this off with the lldb command: `settings set target.process.disable-memory-cache true`.  If the problem is that 0x000000800020a004 is valid memory but 0x000000800020a000 is not, then turning off the cache should fix the problem.

Comment: Memory is mapped by pages, if xxxx_0004 is valid, xxxx_0000 should also be available.

Comment: That is true on normal systems, but not necessarily true on bare metal devices.